# Arg_COMException Error in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, com

One of our clients suddenly got an `Arg_COMException` since last Wednesday (30th Aug 2017).
Here is the error message with the stack trace.

> [Arg_COMException]
>   Arguments:
>   Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.50907.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_COMException
>   Stack track: __________________________________
>   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
>      at MS.Internal.XcpImports...
>   ...

[Here is the full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhRRl.jpg)

Any help would be highly appreciated as this is a production issue.

Comment: I included the error message from the image, improved some formatting/spelling.

Comment: That machine is pretty messed up, it can't even produce a decent exception message.  Underlying reason for the exception is invalid XAML, that should never happen on a production machine of course.  Nothing that a disk format can't solve, this isn't your problem

Answer (score 0):

We identified, some of dropdowns and AutoComplete is causing issue while loading. So hide those controls and make it visible after a short delay one by one. Now the form is functioning. This is kind of workaround.

Still no clue what is causing the issue  and what could be the correct fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Extended ASCII charactors in your XAML or in your data, you may get this error.

In our application we had a one extended ASCII charactor in our XAML which looks like hypen ( '-' ). We assumed it is just an hypen (or minus) charactor. This is causing issue in our application. After changing this, the issue is resolved.